# can i use cloth simulation to create clothing

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a character with a plane over its head as cloth.  I ran the cloth simulation and once the cloth has finished draping over my character, i'd like to save the newly fallen cloth as clothing.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can **Apply** the Cloth modifier.